# Scanning HBase based on two cells

Tags: groovy, hbase

Let's say I have two HBase cells:

- x:y
- x:z

How do I do the equivalent of this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE x_y = ? AND x_z = ?
```

This is the (Groovy) code I have for generating the basic filters:

```
static SingleColumnValueFilter makeColumnFilter(String family, String qualifier, String expectedValue) {
    new SingleColumnValueFilter (
            Bytes.toBytes(family),
            Bytes.toBytes(qualifier),
            CompareFilter.CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),
            new SubstringComparator(expectedValue))
}

def filterz = filters.collect {
    makeColumnFilter(it.family, it.qualifier, it.expectedValue)
}
def fl = new FilterList(filterz)
def scan = new Scan()
scan.setFilter(fl)
def family = 'x'.bytes
t.getScanner(scan).each {
    println "${Bytes.toString(it.getValue(family, 'y'.bytes))}"
    count++
}
```

The print statement shows nothing but nulls even though I'm passing in `x` for the family value and `y`/`z` for the qualifiers. It appears to not be filtering the values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter the rows if the column is not found using [setFilterIfMissing](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html#setFilterIfMissing-boolean-).

Change the makeColumnFilter to :

```
static SingleColumnValueFilter makeColumnFilter(String family, String qualifier, String expectedValue) {
    def colFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter (
            Bytes.toBytes(family),
            Bytes.toBytes(qualifier),
            CompareFilter.CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),
            new SubstringComparator(expectedValue))
    colFilter.setFilterIfMissing(true)
    colFilter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think SingleColumnValueExcludeFilter should do the job.

```
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    SingleColumnValueExcludeFilter singleColumnValueFilterY = new SingleColumnValueExcludeFilter("x".getBytes(),
            "y".getBytes(), CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator("valueY".getBytes()), true, true);
    SingleColumnValueExcludeFilter singleColumnValueFilterZ = new SingleColumnValueExcludeFilter("x".getBytes(),
            "z".getBytes(), CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator("valueZ".getBytes()), true, true);

    FilterList filterList = new FilterList(Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    filterList.addFilter(singleColumnValueFilterX);
    filterList.addFilter(singleColumnValueFilterY);

    scan.setFilter(filterList);
```

More detailed documentation on HBase filters could be found [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/admin_hbase_filtering.html).

Hope this will help.